# How do you save a file in Carrierwave from a custom POST action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm making a custom file uploader in a Controller through a POST action. All that it does is receive a file, and respond with a JSON with the URL of the file (if saved succesfully).

How can I save the file using CarrierWave?

I've created a CarrierWave uploader called DocUploader, and a Controller called Fileuploader. I have a script that sends files to this Controller, by just sending `params[:file]`. DocUploader is not bound to any model, it'd simply save the files without a corresponding database record.

In my routes.rb:

```
post 'fileuploader/upload'
```

In the Fileuploader controller I tried something like this, but obviously doesn't work:

```
def upload
  new=DocUploader.new

  respond_to do |format|
    if new.store!(params[:file])
      format.json { render json: {
          success: 1,
          link: new.url
      }.to_json }
    else
      format.json { render json: { success: 0 }.to_json }
    end
  end
end
```

I get a response of 0 of course.

What's the right way to do it?

EDIT:

This is what I get from the logs:

```
Started POST "/fileuploader/upload" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-30 01:57:15 -0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by FileuploaderController#upload as JSON
  Parameters: {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000004ce4088 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160630-24437-1knyrvj.jpg>, @original_filename="YTehnUF.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"YTehnUF.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}
Completed 200 OK in 377ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Contents of DocUploader is pretty standard, but here:

```
class DocUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "static/files"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [nil, 150]
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

Comment: Is this params coming from rails form?  I mean `multipart` option is available while sending request to server?

Comment: It's coming from a js script that is running within rails. It is not of my making, so I don't know it's real composition, but the form format looks fine to me in the logs. I'll edit the question to show what I get.

Comment: I think you should add the content of your `DocUploader`

Comment: It's pretty vanilla, but there.

Comment: Any solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884463/retrieving-afnetworking-multipart-image-upload-and-saving-to-carirer-wave-saves

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change format helper as such:

```
def upload
  new=DocUploader.new

  respond_to do |format|
    if new.store!(params[:file])
      format.json { render json: {
          success: 1,
          link: new.url
      } }
    else
      format.json { render json: { success: 0 } }
    end
  end
end
```

Not sure that's the problem though, but let me know the result you get from that.

Comment: You removed the `to.json` part only, right? Still the same. The `else` condition does work (as it returns 0), so the only one that's not doing anything is the `store!` part.

Comment: Is this project available on Github? I could help take a look

Comment: I'm afraid not. Sorry. :(

Comment: No worries, just thought it would be better to see/fix the error from your own side than the confined space here.

Comment: I understand. I'm starting to think I mistyped something somewhere. Is what I'm using supposed to work? As in that is how it'd be normally done in a situation like mine?

Comment: Yeah it ought to work. I tried the implementation above on my computer before posting and it works fine